# How to search particular text from a text file using java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I have text file containg multiple times "Vijay Patil" or "Vijay Jeevana Patil" keyword or like that.I have to write a regular expression to search Vijay Patil if there is some text between Vijay Patil like "Vijay Jeevana Patil" it will give also return for that.

Answer (score 0):

Rtoip's suggestion is moving in the right direction, except that it doesn't care how many characters are in between and it is a greedy search, which means it will find the first Vijay and the last Patil.

Try

(Vijay).{0,20}?(Patil)

Note that 20 is arbitrary and should be adjusted depending on the length of potential middle names. The () allow you to capture the first and last names for a replacement expression, such as

$1 $2

BTW, http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html is a great site for testing your regex.